# save a number with a tolerance in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

It is necessary for me to know how to save a number with a tolerance?

For example I have the number 0.3000000001, that I want to save this number by 0.3.

Is there anyone who know a funcion in MATLAB which do this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to round off? try `(round(A*10))/10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to round it off first before saving it. The way to round off numbers depends on how many digits you want to save. For example, If you want to save `a = 3.0001` as `a = 3`, you need to say `a = round(a)`. If you want to save 3 decimal places: `a  =round(a  *1000) / 1000;` 1000 means 3 decimal places.